# Can you use "including" after an uncountable word?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

Can you use "including" after an uncountable word? Because the question is highly context-dependent I will just give you the sentence.

> He watched all of the **porn** including the bad **ones**.

Sorry, I couldn't think of another example, but I don't think "porn" is particularly offensive.

I am seriously wondering how to say this in a grammatical fashion.

Instead of "ones", would you use "one", or does the entire sentence need to be reworded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "ones" is a pronoun, (in this usage) it must refer back to a previous noun or noun phrase, here to "porn". But since "porn" is an uncountable noun, this feels awkward, as the pronoun seems to lack agreement. This could be recast as:

> - He watched all of the porn including the bad examples.
> - He watched all of the porn **films** including the bad ones.

The problem does not seem to me to be the use of "including" but the use of "ones" with the uncountable noun as referant.

For those who want an example not using "porn":

> - He listened to all of the music, including the bad ones. (awkward)
> - He listened to all of the music, including the folk songs. (better)
> - He listened to all of the music, including the bad tunes. (better)
> - He listened to all of the music, including the bad stuff. (better yet)

Comment: What about "he listened to all of the music, including the bad stuff"?

Comment: @blackbird  yes, that works, and avoids the problem eith "ones". I'n fact i'll put it in the answer.

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick, but "one(s)" is actually a common noun, not a pronoun, as evident from the fact that it can take determiners such as "the" and "this", which pronouns can't. As you suggest, it requires a non-count antecedent, but note that the antecedent is not a full NP.

Comment: @Bill According nto https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/one "One" in several senses is a pronoun https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/one lists 3 pronoun senses, including "a certain indefinitely indicated person or thing "  followed by a usage note on "use of one as a pronoun".  MW entry 3 for "one" as pronoun. Both Macmillan & Collins also give a pronoun sense. No room for URLs.

Comment: @bill Cambridge lists "He advised workers around him, especially the younger ones, to be patient." as a pronoun sense. Oxford lists "‘her best apron, the white one’" as a pronoun usage. Macmillan lists "It’s a good book, but his last one was better." as a pronoun usage (https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/one_1) Collins lists "They are selling their house to move to a smaller one." as a pronoun usage (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/one_1). Several of these also list "one" as a determiner, by the way.

Comment: @BillJ The Free Dictionary (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/one) (by American Heritage) has an extensive usage note on "one" as a pronoun.

Comment: I'm talking only about the pro-nominal "one". How can it be a pronoun if it can readily with determiners like "the" and "this"? And like most common nouns, but unlike pronouns, it inflects for number "one ~ ones", thus it is a count noun. There is no pronoun that can do that. It's so obvious that it beggars belief that dictionaries can be so clueless. This is precisely why dictionaries are useless for grammar, as any decent grammarian will tell you!

Comment: @BillJ, can you provide a source that says that this use of "one" is not a pronoun, or even that no pronoun can take a determiner? "One" is certainly used here to stand for a noun, and seems like a pronoun to me. Pronouns can inflect: His/theirs for number; I/me for case.

Comment: Yes, The award-winning and much respected _Cambridge Grammar of The English Language_, by Huddleston & Pullum. Your local library may hold a copy.

Comment: @BillJ The ABA Journal has an article on "The pronoun one" at (https://blog.abaenglish.com/advanced-grammar-the-pronoun-one/?lang=pt)  which says *We can put “the” instead of “that” in front of the pronoun for a similar meaning.*

Comment: @BillJ a mere title is not a citation. Page number or link to specific web page, please.

Comment: Page 1462 and a few others.

Comment: I see that p1462 does include the statement that "one" is what they term a "pro-form" but not a pronoun, and that pronouns cannot take determiners. i see that they also call pronouns a class of nouns, which is not standard grammar. I do not think this distinction useful here on ELL, but if you changed "pronoun" to "pro-form" in my answer above, it would not change the rationale, although it would make the answer less clear to learners, in my view.